Apps Script + Google Doc Daily Meeting Check-In Copy/Paste
SOS to whomever can help! Attempted to create an automated daily copy/paste of templated style copy in a Google Document.
Ideally trying to recopy the exemplified section as it is to the top of the document every day and managed to create a functioning button but now running into formatting options unfortunately. Can definitely simplify the text itself but in case there was a better more logical option for what I'm trying.
Got to the point where I've made it into a button that functions to add plain text but now wondering if there is a better option?
Google Document Sample: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WYJOo-v_UlEOcWpKAV8JID6h6FSGnfdSFoBy9f9GNAQ/edit?usp=sharing
Sample coding:
function onOpen() {
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('CUSTOM')
.addItem('NEW DAY', 'PasteValue')
.addToUi();
}

function PasteValue() {
DocumentApp.getUi();
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var insertedText = cursor.insertText("NEW PROJECTS AND RESOURCING OPERATIONS PROJECT STATUS");
var position = doc.newPosition(insertedText, 12);
doc.setCursor(position);
}

What am I missing?  Appreciate your assistance in advance! 

I would take a look at Body.insertParagraph(0,paragraph)https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-paragraph

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, what is your provided Document? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
